# how can i kill javascript process or stop of all functions further execution

Tags: javascript

i am using asp.net ajax toolkit accordion panel . If any user click on header i want to hide that pane instead of collapse or expand . so i just write following method in javascript 
.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        function courtcase() {
            //var a = document.getElementById("acCourtCases");
            //  var a = document.getElementById('<%= acCourtCases.ClientID %>')

            //var _accordion =
            //document.getElementById('<%= ctrlContainer.ClientID%>').AccordionBehavior.set_SelectedIndex(1).hide(); // expand panel nr.3
            alert('rahul');
            document.getElementById('<%= ctrlContainer.ClientID%>').AccordionBehavior.get_Pane(0).content.style.display = 'none';
            document.getElementById('<%= ctrlContainer.ClientID%>').AccordionBehavior.get_Pane(0).header.style.display = 'none';
            alert('rahul');
            //alert(_accordion);
            // throw "stop execution";
            return true;
        }

    </script>
```

its works for me  . problem is after that function ,  ajax call for accordion and again expand or collapse that pane. and its starting to visible.

Comment: I don't understand that question. Do you want to abort all pending AJAX calls on click?

Comment: yes thats exactly i want that .... no further java script method execute after this function .

Comment: You want them aborted (if they didn't complete by now, never execute their success handlers) or delayed (if they didn't complete by now, only execute their success handlers after this function has completed)? Either way, the handlers will need to anticipate that or be wrapped before added as handlers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Try to override the default events to void AJAX calls (Example: replace onclick event to empty function
2) Then try to hide the accordian using CSS

Comment: i have 10 panes and i want this only for first pane. so if i override defaults one , it will apply on all .

Comment: Try to have a centralized function to make AJAX calls. If the first header is clicked then set some flag. From the AJAX function make calls based on the flag.